# In Textured shading mode, texture does not appear on an object unless the object is selected

Tags: texturing, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine

I have textured a bunch of objects through the UV/Image Editor (*Unwrap UV's > Image > Open Image >* etc.).

For some objects that I've textured in this way, in Object Mode, the texture on the object will disappear when I deselect the object (even whilst I am still in *Texture Shading* mode). The texture is replaced by a pure white (I have *Shading > Shadeless* turned on). Strangely, for some objects, this does not happen at all. I am pretty sure that I followed the same steps to texture each object (exact same workflow pattern in the UI). I double-checked and repeated the UV unwrapping and texturing process for each object. Same problem occurs.

All things considered, it's a minor annoyance, but for some reason it is very disruptive for me. I would rather be able to see all textures for all objects while in the Textured shading mode. What steps should I take?

My Blender version is 2.72b, Windows 7 x86-64, Blender Internal render engine.

Comment: This would seem like a bug maybe . . . I don't have much experience with the BI engine as it has been discontinued.